# What part of speech is "city of", "university of", "county of"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Is there a name for the phrases "city of", "university of", "county of", etc?

As in, City of New York, University of Florida, County of Cork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a kind of apposition, it is called [appositive oblique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Appositive_genitive).

Comment: Thanks! In "The John Smith Company" are "John Smith" and "Company" also appositions?

Comment: @fgregg - definitely yes.